# How can i add a description of gameobject when click on the gameobject?

Tags: unity, c#

I have this DetectInteractable working script attached to Player (FPSController).

I'm using tag to detect interactable objects, each object i want to be interactable i change his tag in the editor to "Interactable". ( Maybe there is a better way to do it without using tag ? It's working but many told me not to use tag. )

I'm using Raycast to hit a gameobject detect if it's "Interactable" and if it does i display on the gameobject his name. For example "Security Door" or "Screen Monitor" or "Surveillance Camera"

Now i want to do that if i hit a gameobject with the raycast and it's "Interactable" if i will click the mouse left button it will display a description text description about the gameobject. But this time i want to use some gui box so it will be in front of the screen in the middle and not on the gameobject.

The problem is that i need to create a script for every "Interactable" gameobject and make that if i click on a button it will display a description.

Then how do i make the script and how can i make that when i attach the script to each gameobject it will make in the inspector a box of text so i can enter and type there the description of the item(GameObject) ?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class DetectInteractable : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera cam;
    public float distanceToSee;
    public string objectHit;
    public Image image;
    public bool interactableObject = false;
    public Canvas canvas;
    public Text interactableText;

    private RaycastHit whatObjectHit;
    private RotateObject rotateobj;

    private void Start()
    {
        rotateobj = GetComponent<RotateObject>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        Debug.DrawRay(cam.transform.position, cam.transform.forward * distanceToSee, Color.magenta);

        if (rotateobj.rotating == false)
        {
            if (Physics.Raycast(cam.transform.position, cam.transform.forward, out whatObjectHit, distanceToSee))
            {
                if (whatObjectHit.collider.gameObject.tag == "Interactable")
                {
                    image.color = Color.red;
                    objectHit = whatObjectHit.collider.gameObject.name;
                    interactableObject = true;
                    interactableText.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                    interactableText.text = whatObjectHit.collider.gameObject.name;
                    print("Hit ! " + whatObjectHit.collider.gameObject.name);
                }
                else
                {
                    image.color = Color.white;
                    interactableText.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                    print("Not Hit !");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                image.color = Color.white;
            }
        }
    }

    public class ViewableObject : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public string displayText;
        public bool isInteractable;
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using tags, I would recommend using [Layers](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html). Then, in your [`Raycast` function, you can specify the layer your interactable objects belong to.](https://forum.unity.com/threads/defining-layers-in-raycast.36349/)

Comment: @Hellium If i understood it right i create a new layer for example call it Interactable and instead changing the tag in each gameobject i change the layer to Interactable and then in the function instead checking if the tag is...i'm checking the layer ? If the GameObject is on layer Interactable then make the rest ?

Comment: @Hellium Then what is the difference between checking against tag or checking against layer ? It's the same idea.

Comment: When calling `Raycast`, you can specify a **layer**. The physics operation of raycasting will check only the elements inside this layer. It will increase the performance and you won't have to check the layer since you know only your interactable objects are in this layer.